# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \arctan(\pi^x)\,dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate the intergal:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \arctan(\pi^x)\,dx.$$

Thank you

Comment: Hint: use symmetry

Comment: I don't believe that there is a closed form solution to this problem.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn No.

Comment: @MuadDib42 There is, $\arctan(\pi^{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\pi^{-x})$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha Result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BArcTan%5BPi+%5Ex%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-pi%2Cpi%7D%5D).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the fact that, for $y \gt 0$,

$$\arctan{y} + \arctan{\frac{1}{y}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/ gives a nasty answer which involves the polylogarithmic function. I take this as evidence that the integral is not elementary. Are you sure you have not misstated this homework problem?

Comment: You just use symmetry......

Comment: Shows a limitation of Wolfram.  I get $\pi^2/2$.